# How do I set a RequireJS context recursively

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs

I'm trying to add Jasmine tests to my Marionette application by creating a specific context for each test containing a map that substitutes all dependencies with mocks except for the module being tested (as described here: http://bocoup.com/weblog/effective-unit-testing-with-amd/).

```
mockRequire = requirejs.config({
    map: {
        '*': {
                'dep1': '../mocks/dep1'
             }
    }
});
mockRequire(['appTest'], function(){...})
```

However since my module appTest has a nested call to require the context is lost:

```
//appTest.js
define([],
    function () {
        ...
        require(['dep1'], function (dep1) {
             //Here is not the mocked dep1 but the real one.
        })
    }
);
```

So the question is how I can tell requirejs to use the same context for all child calls to require/define or if there are any other ways to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Change your module definition so that it requires `require`:

```
define(['require'], function (require) {
```

Without it, you use the global `require`. With it, you use a `require` that has the proper context. From [the documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion):

> Note that "require" is specified as a dependency for the module. This allows the require() function that is passed to the function callback to use the right context to load the modules correctly for multiversion support. If "require" is not specified as a dependency, then there will likely be an error.